# asp.net 4 mvc 2 error

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, replication

when I run the app on server I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.DLL' or one of its dependencies. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.DLL' or one of its dependencies. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)
```

Some points:

- On machines with sql server 2005 installed (from which that dll is copied) the app works. But the server does not have it, so I need to get it to work without sql server.
- The file is in wwwroot/bin folder: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll
- Do I need to include the file in References folder in VS? Set it to CopyLocal?

Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated

--MB

Answer (score 1):

The `Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.DLL` is part of the Replication Management Objects which in turn are part of the [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) pack. The *only* supported  redistribution path for SMO is to use the installer that comes with the SQL Server feature pack download, see [Distributing an Application That Uses SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713979.aspx). You must install the SMO redistributable packet on the server.

Comment: it's not possible to take the dlls the feature pack would install and include them in the app? I guess it's not, that's why you said only, right? (and thanks for the info)

Comment: And the sql server version we use is 2005.

Comment: SQL 2005 has a similar redistributable install pack: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=536fd7d5-013f-49bc-9fc7-77dede4bb075